# Screen flicker and freeze after ram upgrade on laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, display, graphics-card

I recently bought a new ram (8gb sodimm ddr3 1600 which is dual channel 2x4gb; specifically g.skill F3-12800CL9D-8GBSQ) to replace my 4gb ram which is specifically: M471B5273CH0-CK0.

After booting on windows, after a few minutes or so the screen flickers (not BSOD), and I'm unable to do anything. I tried the windows memory diagnostics and it passed all test.

However, when I boot on my other OS which is Linux Mint with the same newly bought ram, it does not cause screen flicker (currently on ~3 hours on this OS with new ram so far no problem).

What might be the problem? I have a laptop (k45vm) that has an intel hd3000 graphics with an nvidia graphics card and have the latest drivers. Is there any setting that should be set on graphics card or anything?

**Edit**

If I put the old RAM back in (on windows), it does not cause the screen flicker problem. Exchanging the places on slots of the new pair of RAM does not improve the situation.

Comment: If you put the old RAM back in, does the issue persist? Did you try a different RAM slot (I can't see many internet pages at work so I can't review your mobo) ? Is this the only RAM stick?

Comment: If I put the old RAM back in (on windows), it does not cause the screen flicker problem. Exchanging the places on slots of the new pair of RAM does not improve the situation

Comment: I tried running memtest86 with 10 tests 3 passes, and it got no error so far. It also began to happen on my linux os. Does that mean that the ram was defective and that I should return it or it's not compatible with my laptop?

Comment: Yes.....  Send it back